# vue img src how to use require, Error: was not found: * ~@/assets/?

Tags: vue.js

path:

```
└─src
    ├─assets
    │  ├─css
    │  └─image
    │    └─a.png
```

code:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <img :src="require('~@/assets/image/a.png')"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

vue.config.js:

```js
chainWebpack: config => {
  config.resolve.alias.set('@', path.join(__dirname, 'src'))
},
```

Error message:

This dependency was not found: * ~@/assets/image/a.png

To install it, you can run: npm install --save ~@/assets/image/a.png

How can I modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use absolute path. No `require` is needed. The vue-loader will [take care of it for you](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html#transform-rules).

Assuming you are in `/components/ImageComponent.vue` file, you can just write it this way:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <img src="./../assets/images/a.png"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

No need for the `.chainWebpack` line in your config file as well.

Comment: I want to use the relative path of `@`, and `require` can help me code to BASE64

Comment: @ebyteebyte `@` alias is already defined in Vue CLI projects. `require` is not needed because Vue CLI does this automatically. You would know if you read the link provided...

Comment: Don't overlook to remove the colon `:` before `src` (which is a shorthand for `v-bind:`)

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to use the binding directive and the `require` statement. Since you have Vue CLI setup, the `@` points to the src folder so it should be able to resolve this path correctly: `@/assets/image/a.png`.

Therefore if you simply set the source to use the alias path it should work:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <img src="@/assets/image/a.png"/>
  </div>
</template>
```